# How to insert item to combobox after binding wpf

Tags: wpf, combobox

I want to add an item to the combobox after binding it.
for example:

```
this.cbCategory.ItemsSource = categoryList;
        this.cbCategory.DisplayMemberPath = "CategoryName";
        this.cbCategory.SelectedValuePath = "CategoryID";
```

i want to add("All", "%") as the first one.

Geetha.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is very simple using a CompositeCollection:

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="CategoryName" SelectedValuePath="CategoryID">
  <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    <CompositeCollection>
      <my:Item CategoryName="All" CategoryID="%" />
      <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding CategoryList}" />
    </CompositeCollection>
  </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

How it works:  The CompositeCollection produes the "All" item followed by all of the items in the CategoryList collection.  Note that `<my:Item ... />` is the constructor for your item class. You will need to change it to your actual namespace and class name.

Important advice:  I notice you are setting some ComboBox properties in code-behind.  This is a very bad practice.  You should use XAML as shown above.

Comment: Hi, I am using the class which is present in the other project of the same solution. public class Category
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the category ID.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The category ID.</value>
        public string CategoryID { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the name of the category.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The name of the category.</value>
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }

Then how i have to call this.

Comment: You can reference any class by setting an appropriate XML namespace.  For example, `xmlns:otherProject="clr-namespace:NamespaceInOtherProject;assembly=OtherAssembly"`.  Then instead of `<my:Item ...>` you write `<otherProject:Item ...>`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll break the binding if you try to add it later and will no longer receive updates.

Why not just add your 'extra' item before you bind it?